# When using getJSON I never get inside the function call

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am implementing towards a [pretty simple API](http://shortswitch.com/admin/api), and have made a simple jQuery app which builds a local URL such as:

```
http://www.example.com?utm_campaign=test&utm_content=status&utm_source=facebook_saxocom&
```

When I call the API, I do it with a URL such as this (API key changed):

```
http://api.shortswitch.com/shorten?apiKey=MYAPIKEY&format=json&callback=?http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%3Futm_campaign%3Dtest%26utm_content%3Dstatus%26utm_source%3Dfacebook_saxocom%26&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.shortswitch.com%2Fshorten%3FapiKey%3D402aaa42317ba1e3b70214740dbec7a5d33a7522%26format%3Djson%26callback%3D%3Fhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.example.com%253Futm_campaign%253Dtest%2526utm_content%253Dstatus%2526utm_source%253Dfacebook_saxocom%2526
```

Here I get the valid JSON back I want (both with and without URl encoding) when I open it in a browser:

```
{
    "results": {
        "http://api.shortswitch.com/shorten?apiKey=MYAPIKEY&format=json&callback=?http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%3Futm_campaign%3Dtest%26utm_content%3Dstatus%26utm_source%3Dfacebook_saxocom%26": {
            "shortUrl": "http://s.domain.com/3M",
            "hash": "3M",
            "longUrl": "http://api.shortswitch.com/shorten?apiKey=MYAPIKEY&format=json&callback=?http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%3Futm_campaign%3Dtest%26utm_content%3Dstatus%26utm_source%3Dfacebook_saxocom%26"
        }
    },
    "errorCode": "0",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "statusCode": "OK"
}
```

My calling function:

```
function createNewShortUrl(url) {
        $.getJSON(url, { longUrl: url }, function (data) {
            if (data.statusCode == "OK") {
                for (var i in data.results) {
                    $('#shortenUrl').val(data.results[i].shortUrl);
                    break;
                }
                return;
            }
            alert(results.errorMessage);
        });
    }
```

I never get inside:

```
$.getJSON(url, { longUrl: url }, function (data) {
```

As: no alert() functions are being called inside the function, and in the Firebug debugger I never hit a breakpoint inside it.

So my question is: what is wrong with my getJSON function? What should I change in order to get the `""shortUrl": "http://s.domain.com/3M"` element out?

**EDIT - my response**

I get a 200 response when calling with the following exact data:

```
?http: //www.dr.dk?utm_campaign=fdfd&utm_content=status&utm_source=facebook_saxocom&({
    "results": {
        "http://api.shortswitch.com/shorten?apiKey=MYAPIKEY&format=json&callback=?http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dr.dk%3Futm_campaign%3Dfdfd%26utm_content%3Dstatus%26utm_source%3Dfacebook_saxocom%26": {
            "shortUrl": "http://s.domain.com/3N",
            "hash": "3N",
            "longUrl": "http://api.shortswitch.com/shorten?apiKey=MYAPIKEY&format=json&callback=?http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dr.dk%3Futm_campaign%3Dfdfd%26utm_content%3Dstatus%26utm_source%3Dfacebook_saxocom%26"
        }
    },
    "errorCode": "0",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "statusCode": "OK"
});
```

Comment: It looks like your `success` handler isn't being called, are you getting a `200` status code from the server?

Comment: Can you add alert(data) or console.log(data) at the starting to check

Comment: @fbynite yes I get a 200 response . I have added the response

Comment: @RaunakKathuria I hit the function createNewShortUrl, but I never get inside the getJSON method at all (no alerts are called)

Comment: Can you update your json with this $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
console.log( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
console.log( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
console.log( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
console.log( "complete" );
});

Comment: add all your params before the callback and, callback value should be just "?" like callback=? [achieve somehow to make your service url having "callback=?" as the last charters of the service url]